# Is it true that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a}$ goes to zero if the amperian loop delimiting $S$ contracts indefinitely?

Tags: maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

I suppose to have an ordinary magnetic field: in the answer I'm not interested to involve Dirac delta: the integral goes to zero. I want to focus on another point: an infinitesimal physical quantity can have a finite time derivative? Of course derivative of zero is zero, but this flux is never strictly zero, and this trouble me because the step
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a} \to 0
$$ 
(when the surface connected to the amperian loop can be taken indefinitely small) is used when we exploit Maxwell equations to fix boundary conditions on the discontinuity between two media. Maybe I'm getting flustered in the slightest thing, but this confuse me and I can't get to the bottom of this problem. How could I see clearly this passage?

Comment: The answer will be found on every introductory books on electrodynamics

Comment: I want integrate my question with what follow. If we start by $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dot{\mathbf{B}}$ and we exploit Stokes theorem we find $\oint_P \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{l} = - \int_s \dot{\mathbf{B}} \cdot d \mathbf{a} $ and if $P$ contract clearly both sides of this equation go to zero: my problem disappear. So now my question is: is it correct, in writing Maxwell equations in integral form, move time derivative outside of the integral? If not, why? (it doesn't look to me self evident, and I see this movement is usually done). If yes see my initial question.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro Yes, moving the time derivative outside of the integral is completely justified so long as $B(r, t)$ is bounded through $r$ for every $t$ (that is $\lVert B(r,t)\lVert_2 < \theta(t)$) and has existing time derivative almost everywhere. *C.f.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris Wow I didn't know this theorem, and its 3d time dependent version guarantee (ordinarily in physics we handle "good" function, we can ignore problems related to pathological ones) that if surface is static 
$$
\int_S \dot{\mathbf{B}} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a}
$$
this shock me because to my eyes these two objects seems very different (why the second can't assume a finite value when $S \to 0$?).

Comment: Is this really a maths question?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that a function can be "small" at a point but have a "large" derivative at that point.  But maybe the confusion is that you're imagining the surface $S$ shrinking in time, so that it's only "small" at one instant.  But the surface doesn't shrink in time - you're taking the limit where it's "small" at *all* times.  And if a function is *always* small, then its derivative is also always small, because $d/dt\ (\epsilon \Phi(t)) = \epsilon\, d\Phi/dt$, where $\Phi = \int_s {\bf B} \cdot d{\bf S}$.  So you don't even have to exchange the time derivative with the line integral if you don't want to - the smallness of the loop integral will make $\Phi(t)$ infinitesimal for *all* times, so it's time derivative will also be infinitesimal.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $\mathbf{B}$ is a continuous (once-differentiable) function, when you look at small enough sizes, $\mathbf{B}$ has a Taylor series, the first term of which is a constant. As you let the loop size shrink, only the constant term matters. But then $\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a}\rightarrow \mathbf{B}\int_S d\mathbf{a}\rightarrow 0$ since the area of the enclosed surface goes to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the interest but my trouble is not why the integral approach to zero when the amperian loop became smaller and smaller. My trouble is: why this infinitesimal flux shouldn't have a finite time derivative?

Comment: It comes down to the order in which take the limit, time derivative, and integral. $\frac{d}{dt}(0)=0$ no matter what. When we take the limit that the integral $\int_S\mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a}\rightarrow 0$, we are left with $\frac{d}{dt}(0).$

The time derivative and integration can be done in either order. If you insist on performing the time derivative first, the expression becomes $\int_S \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a}$.
To be more rigorous, you'll have to learn a lot more real analysis before you can understand the mathematical correctness of this step.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro Here's a theorem that might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#Higher_dimensions.

Comment: I sketched an informal proof of the (as for me, not self-evident) implication
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,t)=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\lim_{x\to 0}\dot{f}(x,t)=0$$
Exploiting derivative definition and then taking limit we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,t+dt)=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,t)+\left[\lim_{x\to 0}\dot{f}(x,t)\right]dt$$
But the first two terms are 0 by premise (which is valid for any $t$) so the last limit too has to be zero. We can see the implication geometrically too. The premise implies that the $x=0$ section of the surface $f(x,t)$ is the $t$ axis, walking on which we cannot find uphill or downhill.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers and comments inspired to me what follow: maybe this is the simplest (and so the best) way to see why $\frac{d}{dt} \int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a}$ vanishes when the loop contracts indefinitely.

I can simply consider a small surface that doesn't vary in time, but it is essential take into account the possibility that the magnetic field (and consequently the flux) does vary. Now, if surface $d\mathbf{a}$ is very small we can ignore the integral and simply write $\Phi = \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{a}$ (in case we are on a media discontinuity we will broke into $\mathbf{B}_1 \cdot d \mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{B}_2 \cdot d \mathbf{a}_2$, this has no effects on next reasoning) from wich 
$\dot{\Phi} = \dot{\mathbf{B}}\cdot d \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{B} \cdot d \dot{\mathbf{a}} = \dot{\mathbf{B}}\cdot d \mathbf{a}$ (remember that the surface is constant in time). Because of the smallness of $d\mathbf{a}$ this can be read $\dot{\Phi}(t) \cong 0$. So the answer is yes: it goes to zero because previous steps show that time derivative too is pushed to zero by the infinitesimal surface.