# Why does the surface integral over the $B$-field in a Stokesian loop tend to zero as the surface tends to zero (boundary conditions)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

I am confused by the standard argument used for deriving the boundary conditions at the interface of two media as told by Jackson, e.g. see [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Electromagnetics_and_Applications_(Staelin)/02%3A_Introduction_to_Electrodynamics/2.06%3A_Boundary_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields).

My question concerns the fact that Jackson says that as the "height" (long side of the rectangular loop) of the loop goes to zero
$$
\int_S \frac{d\vec{B}}{dt} \cdot\vec{n} da = 0 \tag 1
$$
but in the next sentence he says that as as the height goes to zero
$$
\int_S [\frac{4\pi}{c} \vec{J} + \frac{1}{c} \frac{d\vec{D}}{dt}] \cdot\vec{n} da = \frac{4\pi}{c} K \Delta l  \tag 2
$$
(here $K$ is a current density flowing exactly on the boundary, $\Delta l$ is the long side of the loop).

1. How do we prove that the first one goes to zero?
2. Why does the second one not go to zero (I assume it is because the current density is described by a delta function like (e.g. along the $z$ axis) $J_0\vec{e_y}\delta(x)\delta(y)$)? How can we find the right side of (2) mathematically?
3. Why isn't it possible to have an "infinitely local" (time dirivitive of the) $B$-field run along the surface e.g. $\vec{B} = B_0 \vec{e_y}\delta(x)\delta(y)$ analogously to the current density (in the link from above this is called "there can be no pulses in B")? Can the impossibility of the existence of infinitely local $B$-fields be proven using Maxwell's equations?

Comment: For 1 and 3: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253567/179151

Comment: If $B\propto \delta(x)$ then what would be the energy of such field? It would not be finite.